# Switching between queues in cellForIndexPath method

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

My `tableView` is scrolling very slowly because there is a fetch request done in every `cellForIndexPath` method. I have verified this using instruments. The result of the fetch request determines the color of the label inside the cell.

Here is a solution I am using inside the custom cell:

```
func configureWith(myObject: MyObject) {
    titleLabel.text = myObject.text
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let color = self.getColor(forGroup: myObject.group)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.titleLabel.textColor = color
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution?

Edit: Changing qos to userInitiated seems to work slightly better in that the scrolling is still virtually instant and the labels show the right color much faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good solution to handle fetch requests inside scrolling `cellForIndexPath`.

1 Fetch request should be asynchronous, because it may take time
2 Fetch request should be called in table view datasource and not in custom cell, because cell can be reused while scrolling
3 Should apply result of fetch request if cell is visible

Code in class where `UITablView` datasource is implemented-

```
func getColor(forGroup: Int, completion: @escaping (color: UIColor) -> Void) {
  //fetch request
  //request processing...
  completion(resultColor)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
  let myObject = //object for indexpath
  cell.configureWith(myObject: myObject)
  self.getColor(forGroup: myObject.group) { (color) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        //this unwrapping is needed as tableview returns nil if cell is not visible
        cell.colorLable(color)
    }
  }
}
```

In CustomCell file:

```
func configureWith(myObject: MyObject) {
  titleLabel.text = myObject.text
}
func colorLable(_ color: UIColor) {
  self.titleLabel.textColor = color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers consider this changes to optimize:

- cache the result of the fetch request to allow scrolling up/down
- consider a bulk fetch and cache the result
- pre fetch of the values
- add the value to the datasource of label text